# TcpStream is immutable by definition but passed as mutable

Tags: rust

I am doing the last and final chapter in the rust book around making a web server. I cannot wrap my head around why the borrow checker accepts this code.

```rust
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) { // expects mut reference 
    let buf_reader =  BufReader::new(&stream);

    let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK_REASON \r\n\r\n";
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();
    
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap(); // immutable reference 
        handle_connection(stream); // compiler shows no error 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TcpStream` is not a reference, it is an owned object.

Calling `handle_connection(stream)` **moves** the stream from the caller to the callee. That means that `main` no longer has access to `stream` after the call, and the stream is dropped at the end of `handle_connection`.

A mutable reference would be `&mut TcpStream`:

```
fn handle_connection(stream: &mut TcpStream)
```

And would need to be called with an explicit `&mut`:

```
handle_connection(&mut stream)
```

What you have instead is an owned stream that `handle_connection` wants to be able to mutate internally:

```
fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream)
```

Note that `mut` is not an important part of the function's external signature. The `mut` here isn't important to callers. It's an implementation detail. It could equivalently be moved inside the function:

```
fn handle_connection(stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut stream = stream; // Move immutable `stream` to a mutable binding.
    ...
}
```